# JSON responses in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am using an API for my university project, which sends me multiple responses which are all valid JSON.

Both are treated as string in **response.body** so I need to parse them into **JSON** or **ruby object**.

The first one passes through the JSON parser but fails if I use `eval` which returns a **ruby object**

```
{
  apiCode: "SUCCESS",
  friendlyMessage: "All information saved successfully"
}
```

Second one passes through eval and gives me a valid Ruby object but fails as a valid JSON.

```
{
  apiCode: "SUCCESS_WITH_ERRORS",
  friendlyMessage: "Some of the information was not processed",
  successfulIds: [
  {
    ssid: "My Test 1",
    bssid: "2d:8c:e5:5c:bb:b9"
  },
  {
    ssid: "My Test 2",
    bssid: "2a:7d:a4:5c:aa:a7"
  } 
  ]
```

Regards,

Babar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running both your JSON blobs through both [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) and Ruby's `JSON` library results in an error.

The error for the first one is

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{   apiCode: "SUCCESS",
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

and for the second one is

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{   apiCode: "SUCCESS_WI
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

The errors suggest that your JSON should look like (I'm showing the first one here)

```
{
  "apiCode": "SUCCESS",
  "friendlyMessage": "All information saved successfully"
}
```

(which parses successfully everywhere).

Comment: I used JSlint and it shows as a valid JSON object, however it doesn't adhere to some RFC. let me test your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Using `eval` for parsing data coming from some external source is a bad idea, because opens a direct code execution vulnerability.

For parsing JSON there's a build-in parser:

```
require 'json'
ruby_object = JSON.load(your_json_string)
```

For more speed, if you need it, use a dedicated json parser gem like `oj` directly or through `MultiJson` gem.

Also your second json is missing the final `}` so is not valid, also hash keys in json are supposed to be in `"`

Comment: @Babar because it is not valid json, if the error in the API is out of control, but is consistent, you can modify response as string to correct for it